# How to use asynchandler in class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to change my routers into class but I don't know how to wrap the asyncHandler in function inside the class

**userController.js**

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

class UserController {
    async Register(req, res){
        const {firstName} = req.body
        return res.status(200).send(firstName)
    }
}
const userController = new UserController()
module.exports = userController
```

userRouter.js

```
const express = require('express')
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/register', userController.Register)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: router.post('/register', asyncHandler(userController.Register)) as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler docs you have wrap your call back!

Comment: Can you upvote and accept this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use asyncHandler like this,
As per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler)

```
router.post('/register', asyncHandler(userController.Register))
```